# Cannot get searchview in app with material view

Tags: java, android

Im working on an android app in which I am attempting to add a search widget. 
This is my 
**v21\Style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!--  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">-->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    </style>
```

As you can see Theme.Material is commented out. 
This has to be done because if I uncomment my material line I get the error "`You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."`
  Naturally my applications works fine with material design but I have been getting this error "`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference`" on
    "`searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo (getComponentName()));"`
in my main activity as I have been attempting to add searching. I read in another stackoverflow post to correct the error to replace "android" with the name of the app in the menuxml as I have done below 
"`Test:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`"  (but this didn't resolve the error forcing me to change extends to suppress the error.

I have added my Activity.Main file below ( I removed the imports and other methods to save space please let me know if I missed something important).
Would appreciate it if someone could point out why I would be getting nulls on
 searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName())); even after specifying it in mymenu.xml
**MainActivity.XML**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    //   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DatabaseHelper dbHeplper;
    ListView trial;

    ListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //    setContentView(R.layout.test);



    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchActionBarItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchActionBarItem);
        android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchActionBarItem);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ActionBarActivity` is part of the support library for older devices.
You need to use an AppCompat theme as you're using the [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)

If you don't want to support Gingerbread devices you could simply call `extends Activity` as since Honeycomb the ActionBar is default.

Note that you have to call `getActionbar()` instead of `getSupportActionbar()` if you use that in your code.

Comment: hi, when I say "Extends Activity" I get the error" Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference". Secondly I am not calling getSupportACtionbar in my main activity. would you please expound?